# PhpMyAdmin config.default file prints echo twice and other problems

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

I modified PhpMyAdmin **config.default.php** file to allow access only from certain IP addresses.

I added the following lines mat the top:

```
include_once '../allowed-ips.php';
$ipaddress = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

if (!in_array($ipaddress, $allowed)) {
echo "Access denied";
die;
}
```

file **allowed-ips.php** contains allowed IP addresses:

```
$allowed = array("111.111.111.111","222.222.222.222");
```

For some reason script does not allow access from my IP address and exits with "Access denied".

I added the following lines:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

echo $allowed;
```

The script doesn't print anything as `$allowed` and doesn't display any error.

I added one more line:

```
echo $ipaddress;
```

For some reason scripot prints $ipaddress twice. If I add die; after $ipaddress then it prints it only once,

Any ideas? Why script prints `$ipaddress` twice and why echo of `$allowed` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to allow/deny access based on IP and user is using the `AllowDeny` directive of phpMyAdmin. 
See the [FAQ](https://phpmyadmin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=allow#how-can-i-use-the-host-based-authentication-additions) from phpMyAdmin documentation. Also have a look at [AllowDeny(order)](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#AllowDeny_.28order.29) and [AllowDeny (rules)](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config/Servers#AllowDeny_.28rules.29) configurations.